# why is it easier to slide a magnet on a metal surface than to pull it away from the surface

Tags: ferromagnetism

I have some woodworking accessories that use big magnets. It's hard to pull them away from the ferrous surface of my table saw. But it's pretty easy to slide them across the surface. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Same reason it's easy to slide a heavy weight around on a flat table rather than lift it.

The magnets are attracted to the metal table and so you are giving them potential energy by pulling them away, in the same way as you give a heavy weight potential energy by lifting it away from the ground.

Other than friction you don't change the energy by moving it around

Comment: The potential energy from gravity aside, is the magnet "helping" to move itself sideways, but not helping to move itself perpendicularly away?

Comment: No any help the magnet gets from the pull of metal in front is cancelled by the pulling back from the metal behind it. Otherwise you could make a perpetual motion machine !